# How can I create a program which reads from any text file given?

Tags: python, file-io

What I did so far:

```
def readMatrixFile(file):
    '''
    This function reads files
    '''
    fr = open("{}".format(file), 'r') 
    
    # Checking every line whether it is a matrix row or not.
    for line in file:
        print(line)
        
    # close the file
    fr.close()
```

I want to create a function that reads any file given. My code above did not work. What and where did I do wrong? What should I do further ?

Comment: Should be `for line in fr:` instead of `for line in file:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this could work for you:

```py
def readMatrixFile(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            print(line)
```